# How do I stop process running after specific time? Can i use timer for that?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

User form have 2 fields email address and verification status (in.Net).
I am calling email verification plugin once user save form data. 
Requirement is if email verification takes more that 5 seconds then it should stop verification and update email verification status as unable to verify.

I have written the following code by using `Timer`, once timer triggers the `Elapsed` event, my control goes to `OnTimedEvent`. When timer gets elapse then i want to update `isvalid = new OptionSetValue(3)` in thread ValidateEmailAddress. How can I achieve this?

```
        internal void ValidateEmailAddress(ServiceClient sc, Entity target, string emailaddress, string IsValid, string remark, string message)
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000; // 5 second
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        if (emailaddress != string.Empty || (ContainData(target, IsValid) && target[IsValid] == null))
        {
            string[] returnstr = (string[])sc.VerifyEmail(emailaddress);
            string resultValue = string.Empty;
            OptionSetValue isvalid = null;
            foreach (var item in returnstr)
            {
                if (!item.ToLower().ToString().Equals("success"))
                {
                    if (item.ToLower().ToString().Equals("serveriscatchall"))
                    {
                        isvalid = new OptionSetValue(1);
                    }
                    else
                        isvalid = new OptionSetValue(0);
                    resultValue = item;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    isvalid = new OptionSetValue(1);
                }
            }
            if (isvalid != null)
            {
                target[IsValid] = isvalid;
            }
            if (resultValue.Length > 0)
            {
                string returnValue = GetSysConfig(resultValue);
                if (returnValue != null)
                {
                    target[remark] = returnValue;
                }
                else
                    target[remark] = GetSysConfig("Others") + "(Error : " + resultValue + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                target[remark] = null;
            }
        }

     // I need to capture timer elapse event here and then i will update email address as Not able to verify
     // How can i do this?   

}
static void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("0.5 seconds already over");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would work with a static `bool` field in my class if I were you, something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static bool continueOperation = true;


internal void ValidateEmailAddress(ServiceClient sc, Entity target, string emailaddress, string IsValid, string remark, string message)
{
    continueOperation = true;
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 5000; // 5 second
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    if (emailaddress != string.Empty || (ContainData(target, IsValid) && target[IsValid] == null))
    {
        string[] returnstr = (string[])sc.VerifyEmail(emailaddress);
        string resultValue = string.Empty;
        OptionSetValue isvalid = null;
        foreach (var item in returnstr)
        {
            if(!continueOperation)
               break;
            {
              if (!item.ToLower().ToString().Equals("success"))
              {
                if (item.ToLower().ToString().Equals("serveriscatchall"))
                {
                    isvalid = new OptionSetValue(1);
                }
                else
                    isvalid = new OptionSetValue(0);
                resultValue = item;
                break;
              }
              else
              {
                isvalid = new OptionSetValue(1);
              }
        }
        if(!continueOperation)
            isvalid = new OptionSetValue(3);
        if (isvalid != null)
        {
            target[IsValid] = isvalid;
        }
        if (resultValue.Length > 0)
        {
            string returnValue = GetSysConfig(resultValue);
            if (returnValue != null)
            {
                target[remark] = returnValue;
            }
            else
                target[remark] = GetSysConfig("Others") + "(Error : " + resultValue + ")";
        }
        else
        {
            target[remark] = null;
        }
    }

 // I need to capture timer elapse event here and then i will update email address as Not able to verify
 // How can i do this?   

}
   static void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       continueOperation = false;
       Console.WriteLine("0.5 seconds already over");
   } 
}
```